# How to open link in <a href> when click on parent <h3> element?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the problem when click in my title some post. Because I need set title have font-size and line-height is big. When user click between two line, they can't click. If hover in text, it's work.

[I added a red arrow with 2 heads in the middle of the 2 lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYgg1.png) (click on this to see image)

But user not hover exactly all time, so they will try click many time when start read some post in my website.

Code look like that:

```css
.entry-title {
  font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
  padding-top: 2px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 26px;
  line-height: 46px !important;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<h3 class="entry-title">
  <a href="https://google.com">This line very long, have font-size is 26 and line-height is 46px</a>
</h3>
```

I purposely to width 50% to have 2 line in sample code.

Have any method to fix that? User only hover anything on h3 tag, click on h3 tag and will open link in the a href.

So sorry if my first post is bad. I also research in Stackoverflow before ask this question but can't find the question same my case.

I prefer the simple method to resolve that. Thank you very much!!!

Comment: Rethink your HTML and put the `a` outside the `h3`. Then you do not need to do any dirty javascript tricks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you cannot change your HTML structure, you can select all elements with the `entry-title` class using `document.querySelectorAll` and add click event handlers to all of them to click the child anchor tag.

```
document.querySelectorAll('.entry-title').forEach(title => title.addEventListener("click", function(e){
    this.querySelector('a').click();
}));
```

Comment: this working. but I have small question. Is it will affect to performance my website? I have 80-100 post like this at first load my website, when scroll it will lazy load. Click load more with add 20 post and infinity scroll.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var h3 = document.querySelector(".entry-title");
h3.addEventListener("click", function () {
  var a = h3.getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
  a.click();
});
```

```css
.entry-title {
                font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
                padding-top: 2px;
                font-weight: 700;
                font-size: 26px;
                line-height: 46px !important;
                width: 50%;
                cursor:pointer;
            }
```

```html
 <h3 class="entry-title">
            <a href="https://google.com" target="_blank">This line very long, have font-size is 26 and line-height is 46px</a>
        </h3>
```

Comment: the structure theme like that, I can't change that.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**

Use `addEventListener` on `<h3>` and simulate `click();` on `<a>` link

Your example could be:

```js
var h3 = document.getElementsByClassName("entry-title");
for (var i = 0; i < h3.length; i++) {
  var a = h3[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
  h3[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    a.click();
  });
}
```

```css
.entry-title {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  padding-top: 2px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 26px;
  line-height: 46px !important;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<h3 class="entry-title">
  <a href="https://google.com">This line very long, have font-size is 26 and line-height is 46px</a>
</h3>
```

Comment: the theme I use very complex, I can't change it because it can be conflict code and css was write by developer.

Answer (score 0):

Adding padding might help or put everything in a div and add an Eventlistner to the div

div = document.getElementbyid('divid')
div.addEventlistner('click',function(e){

window.location.assign('url')
})

sorry for poor spellings

Comment: I have many title with link same structure. This sample code, I add 1 URL.

Answer (score 0):

Try enclosing the heading itself within the a tags.